# Scoping Issue with SparkContext.sequenceFile(...).foreach in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My objective is to process a series of `SequenceFile` folders generated by calling `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_].saveAsObjectFile(...)`. My folder structure is similar to this:

```
\MyRootDirectory
  \Batch0001
     _SUCCESS
     part-00000
     part-00001
     ...
     part-nnnnn
  \Batch0002
     _SUCCESS
     part-00000
     part-00001
     ...
     part-nnnnn
  ...
  \Batchnnnn
     _SUCCESS
     part-00000
     part-00001
     ...
     part-nnnnn
```

I need to extract some of the persisted data, however my collection - whether I use a `ListBuffer`, `mutable.Map`, or any other mutable type, loses scope and appears to be newed up on each iteration of `sequenceFile(...).foreach`

The following proof of concept generates a series of "Processing directory..." followed by "1 : 1" repeated and never increasing, as I expected `counter` and `intList.size` to do.

```scala
  private def proofOfConcept(rootDirectoryName: String) = {
    val intList = ListBuffer[Int]()
    var counter: Int = 0
    val config = new SparkConf().setAppName("local").setMaster("local[1]")
    new File(rootDirectoryName).listFiles().map(_.toString).foreach { folderName =>
      println(s"Processing directory $folderName...")
      val sc = new SparkContext(config)
      sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
      sc.sequenceFile(folderName, classOf[NullWritable], classOf[BytesWritable]).foreach(f => {
        counter += 1
        intList += counter
        println(s"  $counter : ${intList.size}")
      })
      sc.stop()
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" ...
Processing directory C:\MyRootDirectory\Batch0001...
17/05/24 09:30:25.228 WARN  [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[Stage 0:>                                                         (0 + 0) / 57]  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
Processing directory C:\MyRootDirectory\Batch0002...
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
Processing directory C:\MyRootDirectory\Batch0003...
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
  1 : 1
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures

Comment: Do you see this when Spark is out of the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function inside `foreach` is run in a spark worker JVM, not inside the client JVM, where the variable is defined. That worker gets a copy of that variable locally, increments it, and prints it. My guess is you are testing this locally? If you were running this in a production, distributed spark environment, you wouldn't even see the output of those prints.

More generally, pretty much any function you pass into one of RDD's methods will probably be actually executed remotely and will not have mutable access to any local variables or anything. It will get an essentially immutable snapshot of them.

If you want to move data from spark's distributed storage back to the client, use RDD's `collect` method. The reverse is done with `sc.parallelize`. But note that both of these are usually done very rarely, since they do not happen in parallel.